# Send 404s to custom route in Kohana 3

Tags: php, exception, http-status-code-404, kohana, kohana-3

I've looked at how [shadowhand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49146/shadowhand) (the main guy behind Kohana currently) set up his `bootstrap.php` file to handle exceptions on [GitHub](http://github.com/shadowhand/wingsc/blob/master/application/bootstrap.php#L126).

I thought, "that's cool", so I incorporated something similar.

However, instead of serving up a view, I'd like to send the request to a different route (or at least point it to a controller/action pair).

So this part on GitHub

```
 // Create a 404 response
$request->status = 404;
$request->response = View::factory('template')
->set('title', '404')
->set('content', View::factory('errors/404'));
```

Would be something like (pseudo code of course)

```
 // Create a 404 response
$request->status = 404;
$request->response = Route::get('404_error'); // which will map to a route outlined above in bootstrap.php
```

How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Request::factory with the uri:

```
$request->response = Request::factory('error/404')->execute();
```

Or with the route:

```
$request->response = Request::factory(Route::get('error_404')->uri())->execute();
```

Comment: That last line, the `Route::get()` needs `->uri()` doesn't it?